# Get InputStream out of TarArchiveInputStream

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-commons-compress

I'm getting files from an FTP.
The files I'm getting are either text files or tar.gz

For text files I just send them to S3. If I encounter a tar.gz I want to untar it and save each file with the same method.

```
public void handleFile() {

    try (InputStream fileStream = ftpFileService.getInputStream(file)) {
        if (file.getName().lastIndexOf(".TGZ") > -1) {
            TarArchiveInputStream tar = new TarArchiveInputStream(new GzipCompressorInputStream(fileStream));
            TarArchiveEntry entry = null;
            while ((entry = tar.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
                LOGGER.info("fileName to save {}", entry.getName());
                saveStreamToS3(entry.getName(), new InputStream(tar));
            }
            tar.close();
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("fileName to save {}", fileName.getName());
            saveStreamToS3(fileName.getName(), fileStream);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I tried saving the `entry` directly using `new FileInputStream(entry.getFile())` but this returns null.

Do I need to make a `saveTarStreamToS3()` or can I make an InputStream out of a TarArchiveInputStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileInputStream only reads real files. It doesn't read data from inside an archive.

There are two possible solutions

- Use `InputStream` which FileInputStream and TarArchiveInputStream impliements
- Copy the file to disk, read using FileInputStream, delete afterwards.

The purpose on the interface `InputStream` is so you don't need to know where the data is coming from, and this is the natural way to solve this.

> can I make an InputStream out of a TarArchiveInputStream

TarArchiveInputStream implements InputStream so there is nothing to do.

Comment: @gyc you don't need to cast it when upcasting. you only need to cast it when downcasting e.g. `(TarArchiveInputStream) inputStream` needs a cast.